# I need help understanding view script

Tags: sql

This is a view script, (dbo.Get_Qty_Sum) is a scalar function. I need to understand how the code is combining the scalar function with (c.Schedule_ref, c.Schedule_Line, c.master_part) END) –

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use. Probably sql server.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. We can't know what the views in your database look like unless you post them.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment and readability...

If you are using SQL-Server, you need to get the underlying scalar function.  Edit your original post question and paste what you find in that.  Don't try to post the query as a comment response.

```
In SQL-Server Management studio, expand the databases folder.
Expand the specific database you are querying against (in case there are multiple databases on your server).
Expand the folder for Programmability
Expand the folder for Scalar-valued Functions
Scroll down to the name of your function "Get_Qty_Sum"

Then right-click, select Script Function as, Drop and Create To, New Query Editor Window.
```

This will put the entire query in that window for you to look at.  THAT is what would be needed to edit and post within your original question.  It might even expose to you what your own answer can get, you just did not know how / where it was coming from.